# Root Account Setting in Open Collective Local Development Environment

Tags: node.js, backend, open-source

I have installed Open Collective frontend from GitHub to setup my development environment. I have installed following:

- [Frontend](https://github.com/opencollective/opencollective-frontend/)
- [Open Collective REST API](https://github.com/opencollective/opencollective-rest)
- [Open Collective PDF service](https://github.com/opencollective/opencollective-pdf)
- [Open Collective Images](https://github.com/opencollective/opencollective-images)
- [Open Collective API](https://github.com/opencollective/opencollective-api)

Frontend has Root Actions which are at `opencollective-frontend/components/root-actions`. All installation is on my computer, I have configure the environment variables in files too, but I do not know, how to get password of root user?

I have already checked all the documents, codes and help available at GitHub.

I want to know that how can I configure root user.